# Reduce code trigger class

Tags: jquery, triggers

I want to make the switch classes. Wrote the code, but need this code has decreased in numbers and make it more versatile. Can you please tell how to do it.

```
$('.js_lightSpeedIn').click(function(){
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_zoomIn js_fadeInLeft").addClass("js_lightSpeedIn");
});

$('.js_zoomIn').click(function(){
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_lightSpeedIn js_fadeInLeft").addClass("js_zoomIn");
});

$('.js_fadeInLeft').click(function(){
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_lightSpeedIn js_zoomIn").addClass("js_fadeInLeft");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use variable to make the code more decent. One selector is repeating 3 times, make it a variable.

```
a=$('.js_pro-accordion-menu');
$('.js_lightSpeedIn').click(function(){
    a.removeClass("js_zoomIn js_fadeInLeft").addClass("js_lightSpeedIn");
});

$('.js_zoomIn').click(function(){
    a.removeClass("js_lightSpeedIn js_fadeInLeft").addClass("js_zoomIn");
});

$('.js_fadeInLeft').click(function(){
   a.removeClass("js_lightSpeedIn js_zoomIn").addClass("js_fadeInLeft");
});
```